# List of named lists

Tags: python, list

I need to create a list of named lists in a python script.

What I want to do is create a mklist method that will take strings in a list and create lists named for each of the strings.  So, from here:

```
a = "area"

for i in range(1, 37):
    x = str(a) + str("%02d" % (i,))
    ' '.join(x.split())
```

I want to get the following:

```
area01 = []
area02 = []
area03 = []
area04 = []
area05 = []
area06 = []
area07 = []
area08 = []
area09 = []
area10 = []
area11 = []
area12 = []
area13 = []
area14 = []
area15 = []
area16 = []
area17 = []
area18 = []
area19 = []
area20 = []
area21 = []
area22 = []
area23 = []
area24 = []
area25 = []
area26 = []
area27 = []
area28 = []
area29 = []
area30 = []
area31 = []
area32 = []
area33 = []
area34 = []
area35 = []
area36 = []
```

Any advice?  I can't seem to get it.  Thanks!
E

Comment: What do you mean "named lists"? Are you talking about a dict? what part of it can't you "get"? Also, although redundant, your code looks like it should work to generate the names.

Comment: Are you using Python code to generate Python code, or are you trying to create those lists within your script file? In the latter case you should probably not be doing that.

Comment: A very similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010840/generating-variable-names-on-fly-in-python

Comment: If you're trying to dynamically create variables, the answer is: [**Don't**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18157868/1014938).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This calls for either a list of lists:

```
area = [[] for i in range(37)]
```

Or a dict of lists:

```
area = {i: [] for i in range(1, 37)}        # Python 2.7+
area = dict((i, []) for i in range(1, 37))  # Python 2.6 or earlier
```

Then you can access each item with:

```
area[1]
area[2]
...
area[36]
```

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010840/generating-variable-names-on-fly-in-python) question.

```
a = "area"
for i in range(1, 37):
   x = str(a) + str("%02d" % (i,))
   locals()[x] = []
```

Or use globals() if you want the lists to be global.

That would give you empty list variables area01 to area36.

You should note though that just because it can be done, doesn't mean it should. A better/more readable solution would be:

```
area = [[] for i in range(37)]
```

(see John's solution)

Answer (score -1):

Something like:

```
a = "area"
x = [ "%s%02d = []" % (a, i) for i in range(1,37) ]
print('\n'.join(x))
```

If you want your lists defined in the current Python session you sostitute the last line with

```
for i in range(0, 36):
    exec(x[i])
```

And check with

```
print area01
print area35
```

Note however that [this is not advisable](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.it/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html)

Comment: Considering that I answered what was literally asked, I fail to see how I might have deserved a downvote